# How does lambda x: (x % 2 and 'odd' or 'even') work

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I was learning about lambda functions, and saw this example. I cannot understand how, 'odd', or 'even' is selected.

```
print((lambda x: (x % 2 and 'odd' or 'even'))(3))
```

returns odd

```
print((lambda x: (x % 2 and 'odd' or 'even'))(4))
```

returns even

Comment: I didn't know about that but googling it, it Iooks like it is a ShortHand Ternary expression : look at [ShortHand Ternary (at the end)](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html)

Comment: Both snippets are the same, they both return `odd`; but that just as an aside…You could type those snippets in little by little and see how they work. What do you get for `1 and 'odd'`? `0 and 'odd'`?

Comment: It's a terribly clever (i.e. really bad) way to write `'odd' if x % 2 else 'even'`.

Comment: Thank you all very much! The link proved really helpful.